# What is the equivalent resistance in this case?

Tags: resistance

I can't find anything about this. Any help?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8EWu3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You mean the resistance across the short circuit?

Comment: Across which two points?

Comment: remove R2 to get the equivalent circuit (resistance)

Answer (score 6):

The resistor R2 is shorted and no current will flow in it.
That leaves only one resistor in the circuit, R1.
So if you measure the resistance between left and right connector across R2 you get zero ohm.
If you measure between the top connector and either left or right you see the resistance R1 that is 100 ohm. This is a typical mistake while breadboarding if both connectors of R2 are in the same row.